# Azure webjob Error only on deployment :The account credentials for xxx are incorrect

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, webjob

Hi when I test the standard code for azure web job

```
 static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();


        var host = new JobHost(config);

        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

And I debug the code

```
  public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message);
    }
```

Runs fine.....

When I deploy this same code to the same azure setup I can see I get an error

> 2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error       Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The account credentials for 'travelithotelcontentcode' are incorrect.
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageCredentialsValidator.d__4.MoveNext()
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageCredentialsValidator.d__0.MoveNext()
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageAccountProvider.d__0.MoveNext()
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.JobHostContextFactory.d__b.MoveNext()
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.JobHostContextFactory.d__0.MoveNext()
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.d__f.MoveNext()
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.d__0.MoveNext()
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.Start()
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.RunAndBlock()
>   2018-07-11T11:04:04  PID[4280] Error          at TravelIT.BookingEngine.TravelPortImageWebJob.Program.Main()

Any Ideas why this is only happening when deploying the azure web job?

Answer (score 0):

Check your deployment profile "travelithotelcontentcode"
and check that the credentials (id and password) are the same as the profile taken from the azure app in azure portal.

Otherwise you ould try to create a new profile from scratch and select again the resource you're deploying to, that should update the credentials with the most updated one.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I noticed when we removed the firewall settings the web job ran correctly.....Do you know how to get firewall to accept the app services and web job?